# ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have creating an MVC 5 program using the code first approach for the first time. I had to include some code in my Patient Controller to get some numbers and make them a unique code. This works beautifully.

The issue is that, every time  I re-scaffold when I change my model, I loss that piece of code.  Is there anyway of keeping the code so that it is re written into the controller when re-scaffolding.

I added the code I want to preserve when scaffolding.

```
int N = db.Patients.Max(F => F.PatientID);
N++;
string Nt = Convert.ToString(N);
ViewBag.CardNo = "M" + Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now).ToString("yy")) + BizLogic.Right("000000" + Nt,5);    


return View();
```

I will like to know if the above code can be rewritten once the controller is being re-scaffold.  I wrote the code in myself into my `PatientController`. Also if there is a better way to do it, I will be grateful.

Comment: Scaffolding is good for starting point, but you don't **have** to rely on it in a [real-world apps](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/109533/2949). Actually, you may not want to access a database directly from controller at all.

Comment: Scaffolding is just for starting point, Its used to create simple markup, most the times its OK for simple maintenance pages. Besides that never rely on it. If you need to recreate the Scaffolding, you will start from 0 again.